# FormData image upload in JS

Tags: javascript, form-data

I can successfully upload an image to the server by using the following form:

```
<form id="upload_form" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <input name="image_url" type="file">
  <input id='submit' type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing as above but programatically using the HTML5 FormData() object.

```
var bts_spritesheet;

handleSpritesheetSelection = function(evt) {
  var f, files, reader;
  files = evt.target.files;
  f = files[0];
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    function(e) {
      bts_spritesheet = e.target.result;
    };
  })(f);
  return reader.readAsDataURL(f);
};
document.getElementById('upload_spritesheet').addEventListener('change', handleSpritesheetSelection, false);
```

The following is called when you user clicks on a submit button:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('bts_spriteSheet', bts_spritesheet);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  return console.log('yay its done');
};
xhr.send(formData);
```

My html is just:

```
 <input id="upload_spritesheet" type="file">
```

I've not included or talked about what I'm doing server side because, as I've said, uploading the file using the usual html5 form above works fine so I know it must be my JS code.

Can anyone see why the JS code is producing a 500 servor error, yet the html form version works fine?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the request bodies of your two workflows. Live HTTP Headers in Firefox would prove useful.